# HTML5 Play next video without delay

Tags: javascript, html, video

So i'm trying to stream video in segments without using the MediaSource extension. (Because not all browsers support MSE). Now i'm trying to do this by loading two video elements and play the next one at the right moment. But this has a very tiny delay between switching. I tried to keep checking the currenTime of the video and after a tiny fraction play the next video element. But this doesn't really work that well (audio overlaps, or delay)

Mind you that the video are preloaded and loaded from Blob storage. So the loading shouldn't delay the playback.

How can i make this (Or another solution without flash) play smoothly without using MediaSource extensions?

Comment: https://github.com/loadingdeck/LifemirrorPlayer/blob/master/LifemirrorPlayer.js

Comment: @Parfait The next video is a part of the previous video so this will not work

Comment: Did you find a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use two video elements positioned one on top of the other. The first one should be playing the current part (or chunk) of the video. The second video element should be loaded with the blob that contains the next chunk and be paused. It should also be hidden (you can set `display:'none'` or `z-index:-99999`). And then when the first video element ends (the `end` event is dispatched), call the `play()` method of the second video element, show it, and hide the first one. Rinse and repeat.

This is what the [LifemirrorPlayer](https://github.com/loadingdeck/LifemirrorPlayer) does.

If the chunks of the stream are perfectly encoded and cut then this technique works. Often it doesn't. Common problems are:

- Synchronizing the audio stream is the probably the hardest. After twenty or thirty chunks are played, the audio usually loses sync with the video. This is very annoying for the viewer and hard to detect and fix (i don't know of any solution actually).
- The video element doesn't end. This is usually caused by an encoder that has put too much (or too little) content into a chunk. It can also be caused by improperly cut chunks, by a buggy encoder or decoder.
- Flickering when the two video elements are swapped. This depends on the browser. However most browsers deal very well with this and the swap is quick and smooth.